# What is `definition` in the Azure DevOps rest API (GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition})

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In the Azure DevOps, we can get the latest successful build using following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Latest/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#definitionreference)

The usage is:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

However, it is not clear to me what is `definition`. In one of my projects, I have two pipelines `Senna.CI` and `Senna.Release`. If I pass `Senna.CI` as definition, it is working but not for the `Senna.Release`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Latest/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#definitionreference) also did not help much.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> definition name with optional leading folder path, or the definition id

The best is to give the definition id, you can find it in the URL (when you the last pipeline runs):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_build?definitionId={id}
```

[image]

So, just take the definition id from the end of the URL, in this case: `13` and put in the api call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/13?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: This would give you html result not the json, also the api listed in question returns the last successful build not all the builds

Comment: You need to take only the ID in the end of the URL, in this case: 13, and put it in the api call: `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/13?api-version=6.0-preview.1
`